# Ffmpeg/lavfi Is it possible to fade out an image overlay that was loaded with a movie= filter not a -i parameter

Tags: ffmpeg, lavfilters

I've tried something like:

```
movie='overlaylogo.png',fade=out:st=5:d=1[logo],[in][logo]overlay='0:0'[out]
```

But it seems to stick on 100% opacity, adding in a `loop=loop-1` and `fps=24` filter after the `movie=` load seem to have little effect, is there some step required to convert an image into a video for fade to apply over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to keep your stream alive so the `fade` filter can do its job. An image input dies immediately after it sends out its frame.

With `-i` we'd do

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png \
       -filter_complex [1:v]fade=out:st=5:d=1:alpha=1,[0:v]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[out] \
       -map [out] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

The `-loop` `image2` input option keeps the stream alive. The same thing must be done with `movie` source filter. It has `loop` option but with a caveat: "Note that when the movie is looped the source timestamps are not changed, so it will generate non monotonically increasing timestamps." So, you need to add `setpts` filter to establish monotonically increasing timestamps yourself:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -vf movie=logo.png:loop=0,setpts=N/FR/TB,fade=out:st=5:d=1,[in]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[out] \
       output.mp4
```

P.S., `loop=-1` (not `1`) should also work (and it likely won't need the `setpts` filter to fix the timestamp).

Comment: Easier to use the loop filter. `movie=logo.png,loop=-1:1:0.fade=`